# When to use "case" and when to use "with select"

Tags: vhdl

Assume we want to output a 4 bit number (swr) to a 7-segment display (seg). In the first approach I use the case statement:

```
process (swr)
begin  
   case swr is
     when "0000" => seg<="1000000";
     when "0001" => seg<="1111001";

     -- and so on...

     when others => seg<="-------";
   end case;
end process;
```

Or I could use the "with select" statement (this time not within a process):

```
with swr select
  seg<= "1000000" when "0000",
  "1111001" when "0001" ,

  -- and so on...

  "-------" when others;
```

Can you please tell me what are the differences between these two approaches? (one faster than the other?, or uses more logic gates? or ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'll produce substantially the same logic (or at least if they don't I'd file a bug :)

As far as the simulator goes they should have the same effect too - the second form creates an implicit process sensitive to `swr` which is the same as your more explicit first form.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is one is a sequential statement and must occur inside a process, while the other is a concurrent statement and appears outside of a process.  The selected signal assignment (with swr select ...) is essentially a short-hand notion for creating a process along with the appropriate sensitivity list and case statement.